# Change background for the selected tab

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, tabs

I thought I did everything right but my code doesn't work. I intend to change the background for the selected tab. Here's my trial.

```
<script>
$('#navigation li').click(function() {
        $('#navigation li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        
    });
</script>
```

The html is here

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link " href="{% url 'home' %}" id="nav">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
         
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'view' %}" id="nav">Work</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the active class

```
<style>
    .active{background-color:black}
</style>
```

I've tried making comparisons to available examples here on stackoverflow but not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to accomplish your goal with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
    .active{background-color:black}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navigation">
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this.id)" class="nav-item" id="home">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
         
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this.id)" id="work" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="work">Work</a>
    </li>
</ul>
  <script>  
    function changeBackground(id) {
      // First remove all "active classes"
      let otherElements = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item")
      for (index=0; index < otherElements.length; index++) {
        otherElements[index].classList.remove("active")
      }

      // Then add the class to the just clicked element
      let clickedNavItem = document.getElementById(id)
        clickedNavItem.classList.add("active")
      
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```